# phpmailer PDF attachments suddenly sent as text attachments

Tags: phpmailer

We have a cript that mails us attachments in PDF format.
Worked for years and suddenly stopped working.

PDF's now are created and mailed, but not mailed as PDF, but as textfiles instead, with .txt extension.

```
    $mail_handler = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
//$mail_handler->Body = $contents_mail_handler;
$mail_handler->Body = $contents_mail_handler;

$mail_handler->From = MAIL_SENDER;
$mail_handler->FromName = MAIL_SENDER;
$mail_handler->Subject = "#$inserted_order_id: $name - € $total";
$mail_handler->AddAddress($email_handler, $email_handler); 

$file_nl = "_orders/" . $filename_nl;
$mail_handler->AddAttachment($file_nl,$filename_nl);             // attachment

$file_en = "_orders/" . $filename_en;
$mail_handler->AddAttachment($file_en,$filename_en);             // attachment

$file_fr = "_orders/" . $filename_fr;
$mail_handler->AddAttachment($file_fr,$filename_fr);             // attachment

$mail_handler->Send();
$mail_handler->ClearAddresses();
$mail_handler->ClearAttachments();
```

text attachment content example : http://pastebin.com/tdfKfQCq

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!
Bas

Comment: Echo out the filename variables and check if the output ends with ".txt"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Path was ok. Updated phpmailer, fixed the problem.